# Can Quill BlockEmbeds use arbitrary tags?

Tags: javascript, quill, parchment

I've got a bunch of components (pieces of html and logic) that I want to be able to embed inside a Quill document, and I'm not entirely sure how to get started. Each component has a single root element, but the tagName is arbitrary (there are `aside`, `div`, `section`, etc tags). Each of the components has a completely non-Quill editing experience (that's handled elsewhere), so ideally their deltas would just look like this:

```
{
  ops: [
    { insert: 'Hello', attributes: { bold: true } },
    { insert: { component: 'domain.com/components/image/instances/foo' } },
    { insert: 'World!\n' }
  ]
}
```

I believe I read somewhere in the documentation that block-level Blots must specify a `tagName` *or* a `className`, but I can't find the reference for that. [All](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/master/docs/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment.md#dividers) of the [examples](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/master/formats/video.js) I can find using the `BlockEmbed` specify a `tagName`, and the [Parchment docs](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#embed-blot) don't really explain it. Is there a *correct* way this should be done, and are there any edge cases I should be aware of?

All of these components would be block-level, so (from my reading of [this issue](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1172)) I don't think selection should be a problem, right?

Comment: I believe https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#blots is the reference you are looking for. I'm planning on writing more/better docs for Parchment but it sounds like you want to inherit BlockEmbed (blots/block.js) since the editing experience is elsewhere.

Comment: Ah yep, that's what I was thinking of. Specifically, "At the very minimum a Blot must be named with a static blotName and associated with either a tagName or className" What happens if I define a className but not a tagName? I can't find any examples of this in practice (from StackOverflow, github issues, etc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have a looks [here](https://codepen.io/k3no/post/a-look-at-quill-js) and [here](https://quilljs.com/guides/building-a-custom-module/)

if your purpose is create a tag which is not  present  in QUILL
what you have to do is something like this:
**CONFIGURE YOUR CUSTOM TAG**

```
 var Embed = Quill.import('blots/embed');
class MyCustomTag extends Embed {
    static create(paramValue) {
        let node = super.create();
        node.innerHTML = paramValue;
        //node.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
        //node.addEventListener('click', MyCustomTag.onClick);
        return node;
    }

    static value(node) {
        return node.innerHTML;
    }
}

MyCustomTag.blotName = 'my-custom-tag';
MyCustomTag.className = 'my-custom-tag';
MyCustomTag.tagName = 'my-custom-tag';
//in case you need to inject an event from outside
/* MyCustomTag.onClick = function(){
     //do something
 }*/

Quill.register(MyCustomTag);
```

**USE YOUR CUSTOM TAG**

```
this.editor.insertEmbed(
0, //INDEX_WHERE_YOU_TO_INSERT_THE_CONTENT, 
'my-custom-tag',//THE NAME OF YOUR CUSTOM TAG
 '<span>MY CONTENT</SPAN>'// THE CONTENT YOUR TO INSERT 
);
```

Pay attention, as default this custom will get the attribute `display: block`
you can target it by css rule as example

```
my-custom-tag {
   display : inline;
}
```